# How to generate Android APK file from Linux ARM64 with dotnet CLI?

Tags: c#, android, .net, .net-core, avaloniaui

I'd like to cross compile from a Linux ARM64 (Raspberry Pi OS ARM64) that has the .NET 7 SDK installed.

The application is targeting NET 7 Android (net7-android).

I've tried with

```
dotnet publish -f:net7.0-android -c:Release
```

But I'm getting this error.

> $ dotnet publish -f:net7.0-android -c:Release MSBuild version
> 17.5.0+6f08c67f3 for .NET /home/jmn/.dotnet/sdk-manifests/7.0.100/microsoft.net.sdk.android/WorkloadManifest.targets(3,5):
> error : Could not resolve SDK "Microsoft.Android.Sdk.net7". Exactly
> one of the probing messages below indicates why we could not resolve
> the SDK. Investigate and resolve that message to correctly specify the
> SDK.
> /home/jmn/.dotnet/sdk-manifests/7.0.100/microsoft.net.sdk.android/WorkloadManifest.targets(3,5):
> error :   SDK resolver "Microsoft.DotNet.MSBuildWorkloadSdkResolver"
> returned null.
> /home/jmn/.dotnet/sdk-manifests/7.0.100/microsoft.net.sdk.android/WorkloadManifest.targets(3,5):
> error :   The NuGetSdkResolver did not resolve this SDK because there
> was no version specified in the project or global.json.
> /home/jmn/.dotnet/sdk-manifests/7.0.100/microsoft.net.sdk.android/WorkloadManifest.targets(3,5):
> error :   MSB4276: The default SDK resolver failed to resolve SDK
> "Microsoft.Android.Sdk.net7" because directory
> "/home/jmn/.dotnet/sdk/7.0.202/Sdks/Microsoft.Android.Sdk.net7/Sdk"
> did not exist.
> /home/jmn/.dotnet/sdk-manifests/7.0.100/microsoft.net.sdk.android/WorkloadManifest.targets(3,35):
> error MSB4236: The SDK 'Microsoft.Android.Sdk.net7' specified could
> not be found.
> [/home/jmn/SeaweedFS-GUI/SeaweedFS.Gui/SeaweedFS.Gui.Android/SeaweedFS.Gui.Android.csproj]

Comment: As the error message suggests, see what's in your `project or global.json`? More help could be given if you provide these relevant config files.

Comment: Possibly related: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/199605622